# How to send 1M emails a day with postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, ubuntu-18.04

I've set up and configured postfix on a test server. it seems to be working. I can send emails to Gmail accounts and I see the email. I've even set it up and running on nodejs. I  want to configure this server to reach 200,000 Emails an hour and 2M emails a day. All emails will be about 1MB. I'm aware that data charges apply and I've calculated the data cost for 30TB.

1. What are the server specs required for such a task. my test cloud server has 32GB of RAM, 8 dedicated cores and 2SSDs. Network speed is about 350mpbs on avg.
2. Should I use some different load balancing methods?
3. Emails are stored in a MySQL DB. ive made a nodejs file which has a for loop to get 100 emails from the db and send the email to the following 100 before sending more. any suggestions?
4. Anything else I need to know?

Comment: What are you going to send that justifies scaling from zero to 50 mails a second faster than progressively upgrading hardware can support?

Comment: it's an email marketing system. i'm sending to send marketing emails using it.

Comment: Prepare to be blacklisted by every major email provider...

Comment: You seem to be missing part of the equation and considering  only part of the challenge ; successfully  generating your messages and sending mail doesn’t do you any good, unless your intended recipients actually receive your messages. That means for starters you don’t send spam and you also try not to look like a spammer. Learn how recipients (and their mailservers) respond to your mail. Coming from nowhere and then sending large volumes of mail generally won’t result in a good delivery ratio. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Postfix tuning is not necessary - start to tune Your knowledge about E-Mail System, base on Your questions You have no idea how its working.
2. Your Postfix client (in that case is not a server) could have 512MB RAM and 1 CPU - what is important - You need fast connection
3. Your Postfix client is not important in that case - important is E-Mail Server to which You are trying to deliver messages (are You sure that some one (let say: gmail.com ) will accept 300 000 E-Mails from Your host in one day ? - hahhaha :D - they will cut Your connection immediately and write in Your maillog - please come back later ;) )
4. Loadbalancing ? What for ? - If You are sending message to 500 gmail.com users Your host should establish max 1 connection and using it deliver package of E-mails to gmail.com
5. If You will start to send massive amount of E-mails Your host will receive also big amount of bounces ;) - be ready for it ;)
6. If You have a fresh IP without reputation - You will be blocked for many hours each time when You will try to resend again big amount of E-mails (by many service providers).
   ... and so on... and so on...

If You would like to deliver big amount of E-Mails, first understand how SMTP protocol is working. On the beginning, I suggest You to rent massmailing service.